# Is this an opinion question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, too-broad

This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/338452/76981) is put on hold as opinion based. The tldr version of the question is "Why are some people saying Frequentist statistics is no good?".

I have partial sympathy with putting it on hold. One the one hand, I don't actually think it's an opinion based question. The OP is not asking "Are Frequentist statistics no good?", but rather wants to really understand the reasoning behind that argument. I do admit that distinction is a grey line: someone might think a reasonable answer is "because they don't understand math", which would help no one (also not my opinion). Also, I do have the fear that it will could turn into a highly-opinion based set of answers.

With that said, one of the reasons I chose to answer it is that I think it's a very important topic worth discussing. I know there have been several somewhat similar questions (i.e. Bayesian vs Frequentist: pros and cons), but I do think this one is a bit more of a niche.

Is CV the right place for such a question? Or is it better suited for something like a blog post?

Comment: I see that I was the last person of 5 to vote against that question. I would have (could have) downvoted it on several grounds, not just that reported as the expressed community view. It's not that it doesn't touch on interesting and important issues: rather, its wording and its links more or less doomed it to be seem too broad as well as too contentious.

Comment: I should add that I liked your answer and upvoted it. Contradictory? I guess so.

Comment: @NickCox: good answer, wrong forum is a completely defendable position

Comment: At this time, it's a tie between closing for reason A or closing for reason B. Seems like the correct course of action is pretty clear.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is debatable whether this Q is "primarily opinion-based" (our closing reason) or not, but it seems to me that it is *clearly* "too broad". It asks about classical statistics vs machine learning, then about frequentist statistics vs Bayesian statistics, and then about book recommendations on "good" statistics. A poor question that should be closed.

If I had had a chance to vote, I would have voted to close as too broad.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is too opinion based for CV. A blog post would be more reasonable.

Comment: I'm mixed on this. It is (another) opportunity for petty B vs A pontificating, & we have several of those already, so it could be a duplicate. OTOH, your answer is balanced (& good, +1). However, it was voted to close by 5 CV users, including both Bayesians and frequentists, with high reputations & who contribute frequently. That's the standard the SE system uses. As a result, I'm inclined to let the closure stand.

Comment: I agree that it is opinion based because what could possibly be a "right" answer here? The blogs that were linked speak for themselves. Would a "right" answer merely parrot the views expressed on the blogs? If the OP has trouble understanding the points in the blogs he/she linked, they should post asking for clarification, but that is not the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is an important discussion topic. It belongs on CV.

Comment: Note: it would be better for people to only upvote their choice, & not also downvote the option they disagree with. That policy will yield the clearest picture of the community's preferences.

Comment: @gung As we won't know who voted once, twice or three times interpretation is fraught any way....

Comment: @NickCox, it's a bit late now, but if no one had downvoted, the picture would be clearer. That's my point.